# How do I create an easily accessible directory outside of /Users/<my username>?

Tags: macos, permission

I want to sync/backup my entire Home (/Users/) directory to other computers using Bittorrent Sync.  Right now my Home directory contains my DropBox folder, which (at 17GB) I do not want to be part of this sync/backup.

I thought an easy way to do this would be to create a Dropbox directory at the /Users level, but even after I set the permissions of that directory to 777, the Dropbox app won't let me move Dropbox there.

I understand that an alternative is to exclude just the Dropbox directory from the Bittorrent Sync (I assume that's possible - I haven't tried it yet), but I think it would be cleaner to have an easily accessible but separate (outside my Home) directory. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What error does the Dropbox app give?

Comment: It's not about an error - it's that I don't want to be syncing my 17GB Dropbox data (which is already synced to all my different computers via Dropbox) AGAIN via BitTorrent Sync.  It's a waste of data and/or a potential sync cluster**** if BT Sync and DropBox are both trying to sync the same folder.

Comment: I was asking re " the Dropbox app won't let me move Dropbox there."

Comment: I did find that adding "/Dropbox*" to the .SyncIgnore files on BOTH sides (Mac side and linux side) keeps the Dropbox folder from being synced by BT Sync.  So that's 99% of what I want.  I'm still curious if there's a way to set up a folder on the Mac's primary drive with normal user permissions outside of the user's Home folder, so I'm leaving the question open.

Comment: Ahh...Dropbox error was "Error with selected folder / Can't create a Dropbox folder in the requested location".  That's all she wrote...  I tried it both with no DropBox folder (so the app could create it) and with an existing Dropbox folder with 777 permission.  Same error in both cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my Dropbox directory to /links/Dropbox with no problems the Dropbox app created a subdirectory Dropbox there. I created this directory with New Folder from the Finder

```
links mark$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 mark      admin  102 25 May 17:18 Dropbox
drwxrwxrwx   3 mark      admin  102 30 Nov 20:10 V
drwxr-xr-x   5 mark      admin  170 30 Nov 20:32 VirtualMachines
```

and

```
links mark$ ls -l Dropbox/
total 0
drwx------@ 24 mark  staff  816 25 May 17:18 Dropbox
```

Comment: Where/what is the "/links" directory?  When I "cd /links", I get "cd: /links: No such file or directory"...

Comment: That is just a directory I have for all non standard directories (named when I had much smaller disks and so had to link across file systems) - It just shows Dropbox can use other directories

Comment: Well that was my basic problem - I didn't know how or where to create a directory in OSX that's not under my user directory that other programs like DropBox could use (I was trying to use Finder, which was a mistake, at least until I discovered Command-^).  I did some more digging and figured out how to create a new directory at the root level of my harddisk, changed the permissions, and Dropbox is now happy.